# Cannot open an HTTPS connection to GitHub in R

Tags: r, github

I am trying to fetch some data in R from a github repo, but the connection fails.

```
remote.file = function(URL) {
    temporaryFile <- tempfile()
    download.file(URL,destfile=temporaryFile, method="curl")
    return( temporaryFile )
}

URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sidooms/MovieTweetings/master/latest/ratings.dat"

Ratings = read.table( remote.file(URL), sep = ":", header=FALSE ),c(1,3,5,7)]
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: I don't have the problem here, `download.file(URL,destfile=tempfile(), method="curl")` works like a charm. Perhaps you don't have writing access on your machine? Also, there is a typo in your last line, it should probably read `header=FALSE)[, c(1, 3, 5, 7)]`

Comment: Try this read.table(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sidooms/MovieTweetings/master/latest/ratings.dat"))

Comment: Please include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your post.